# A generic method that takes a type, modifies its base class property, returns the type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a requirement where:

I have a base class and a set of derived classes:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public bool IsGood {get; set;}
}

public class DerivedClassA : BaseClass
{
    public bool CanTalk {get; set;}
}

public class DerivedClassB : BaseClass
{
    public bool CanGrowl {get; set;}
}
```

For each of the derived classes (`DerivedClassA`, `DerivedClassB`), I have  duplicated code where

1. I have a method that takes the derived class (`DerivedClassA`, `DerivedClassB`),
2. modifies the common property of the base class (`IsGood`)
3. returns the derived class

It would seem that I would be able to remove the duplication by using generics.

My pseudo-code would look something like the following:

```
//not sure what the signature should look like
public T MakeGood<T>(T thing) 
{
    //gets either DerivedClassA or DerivedClassB
    //sets base property IsGood to True
    //return either DerivedClassA or DerivedClassB
}
```

**Anything I can do using generics?**

**Can this be achieved without modifying the class structures?**

Apologies in advance if the solution already exists.

Comment: "I have a method that takes the derived class (DerivedClassA, DerivedClassB)" Do you mean you already have an instance of the appropriate class or should that method create that instance upon the provided type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, set a type constraint on `T`.

```
public T MakeGood<T>(T thing) where T : BaseClass
{
    thing.IsGood = true;

    return thing;
}
```

I do however doubt whether this method is very useful in its current form. The method should actually be static since you don't seem to use instance properties. And why returning `T`?

Comment: "And why returning T" I suppose OP actually wants to *create* the instance within that method, as seen in my answer. But it´s not clear, though.

Comment: Thanks Patric, this is exactly what I wanted. You're right, it will be static. It's a special case where I have a common, `BaseResult` used by multiple services(different projects, different solutions). Depending on the operation, each has it's specific, derived result (like `DebitAccountResult`, `CheckFundsResult`)...when an error/exception occurs, I build an error response that uses properties in BaseResult while preserving the contents of the specific operation's result (like `DebitAccountResult`, `CheckFundsResult`)...hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Use a type constraint:

```
public T MakeGood<T>(T thing) where T : BaseClass {
  …
}
```

can only be instantiated for types `T` where `T` is dervived from `BaseClass`. See *[Constraints on Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the reference. Had to choose Patrick's because I tried his solution as soon as I saw it, and it worked. +1

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you want to make this a method? It seems like a code smell for what you say... I would need to know more about the process.

Consider using `virtual` property and override it in the child classes.

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public virtual bool IsGood {get;}
}

public class DerivedClassA : BaseClass
{
   public override bool IsGood {get { return CanTalk; }}
   public bool CanTalk {get; set;}
}

public class DerivedClassB : BaseClass
{
   public override bool IsGood {get { return CanGrowl; }}
   public bool CanGrowl {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely sure. You are right that you would need to have an appreciation of the context. Thanks for the suggestion anyways